# Django: get url names from urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-urls

The common url syntax for Django application is as following

```
url(URL_PATTERN, VIEW_ACTION, NAME)
```

Since I declared my urls I want to get the list of my urls using some sort this `urls = get_urls(application)` and get the output as a list of urls, I also found the same function used in Django admin application, but I couldn't figure it out.

Is there any built in functions to get this done?

Sultan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reuse the code used by [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions) [`show_urls()`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions/blob/master/django_extensions/management/commands/show_urls.py) command.